# How to subtract dates in MS Access when fields also having only text in few rows

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am subtracting field1 in field2 as below (also attached), but few cells not having date instead it will be having some text. Those having text in either of the field I should get result as "Date not found" . Its easy in excel to use `IFERROR` function but how can we do this in ACCESS as data type is the issue. Please provide me systex to solve it. Thank you in advance!

```
  Field1      Field2     Subtract Result
10/22/2014  11/22/2014     31
10/23/2014  11/23/2014     31
10/24/2014  11/24/2014     31
No date     11/25/2014     Date not found
No date     11/26/2014     Date not found![enter image description here][1]
10/27/2014  11/27/2014     31
10/28/2014  no date Date   not found
10/29/2014  no date Date   not found
10/30/2014  11/30/2014     31
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your getting your data into access, or what you have tried yet if anything, but if you're importing from a file, I would do the following...

Import the data into a staging table

1. Import the data into a staging table named "tblTable" where Field1 and Field2 are of text data type.
2. Create the query below...

   ```
   SELECT tblTable.Field1, tblTable.Field2, IIf(Not IsDate([Field1]) Or Not 
   IsDate([Field2]),"Date not found",DateDiff('d',[Field1],[Field2])) AS DayDiff
   FROM tblTable;
   ```

This will give you the results you're looking for. However you can always change this query into an append query to save the results into a final result table.